# How to overcome a missing msvcrt module when installing Python 3 from source on OpenSuSE Linux?

Tags: opensuse, python3

In order to test a fresh version of a Python app, I need to install the last stable version of Python on my OpenSuSE 15.4 machine /* which by default comes with Python 3.6 */. So I downloaded Python 3.10.11 and built it. `make install` did work, but the next command did not because of a missing `msvcrt` module:

```sh
╭─jacek@epica ~/bin/tmp/Python-3.10.11/dist/bin  
╰─➤  ./python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip 
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jacek/bin/tmp/Python-3.10.11/dist/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 69, in <module>
    import msvcrt
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'msvcrt'
```

Is the missing module really the interfact to the Microsoft Visual C++ runtime? If yes, why is it required when installing Python on a Linux machine?? There is apparently only one flavor of source tarball (albeit in 2 different archive formats) on the Python website. The python home / dir variables are not set at all, BTW:

```sh
╭─jacek@epica ~/bin/tmp/Python-3.10.11/dist/bin  
╰─➤  echo $PYTHONHOME                                                       1 ↵

╭─jacek@epica ~/bin/tmp/Python-3.10.11/dist/bin  
╰─➤  echo $PYTHONPATH

╭─jacek@epica ~/bin/tmp/Python-3.10.11/dist/bin  
╰─➤
```

Setting the python home dir manually (in my case: `/home/jacek/bin/tmp/Python-3.10.11/dist`) doesn't help, though.

Comment: msvcrt is a windows binary.  this looks like you downloaded the wrong version. [1](https://travis-ci.community/t/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-msvcrt-how-to-fix/1667/2) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66814603/pip-is-not-working-error-no-module-named-msvcrt)

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas That's exactly the problem I've got: Python does NOT offer different source tarballs for Windows, Linux etc.! The suggestion to symlink $PYTHONHOME/lib to $PYTHONHOME/lib64 won't work either, as both of them are ordinary folders with different contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found the solution in a (fairly old) following posting at StackOverflow:

[Python 3.7 install not working on openSUSE Leap 42.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51201459/python-3-7-install-not-working-on-opensuse-leap-42-3?rq=1)

It reads as follows:

```sh
ln -s $PYTHONHOME/lib64/python3.10.11/lib-dynload/ $PYTHONHOME/lib/python3.10.11/lib-dynload
```

But please don't ask me why the configure process doesn't create the symlink.